# How can i know if printer was cancelled via javascript?

Tags: javascript, printing

When I click in a button the event trigger `window.print();` and I need to know if the user canceled the print or not. Is that possible?

Comment: Nope. This is outside your web site's control.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript can't check outside events!